# Better way to add "close modal" button in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This works, but I'm sure there is a much better way to do this. Please look at the `document.getElementsByClassName()` part near the bottom.

html:

```
<modal>
  <a slot="trigger">Show Modal</a>
  <h3 slot="header">My Heading</h3>
  <p slot="body">Here is the body of the modal.</p>
  <div slot="footer">
    Here is the footer, with a button to close the modal.
    <button class="close-modal">Close Modal</button>
  </div>
</modal>
```

Modal.vue:

```
<template>
    <span>
      <span @click="show = true">
        <slot name="trigger"></slot>
      </span>
      <slot name="header"></slot>
      <slot name="body"></slot>
      <slot name="footer"></slot>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return { show: false }
        },
        mounted(that = this) {
          document.getElementsByClassName('close-modal')[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
            that.show = false;
          })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is and it's to emit close event from within modal component and than handle closing in parent component when close emit is received. I can't take credit because I saw this on official vue site [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html).

Basically in modal template

```
<button @click="$emit("close")">close </button>
```

And then in component where you use modal add open modal property in data

```
data:  function () { return { open: false }}
```

And when you use modal component

```
<modal @close="open = false">...</modal>
```

Mind @close is the event you emitted from modal it can be whatever @die works if you used $emit ("die") in modal.

And when you want to open modal you can use similar approach

```
<a @click="open = true">open modal</a>
```

If you do this its data driven and easy to reuse.

**edit**

Ok so if you want to add buttons from outside of modal component then define your slots and just add a button in one of those slots or all of them that will make `open = false`

Comment: I want to put the <button>close modal</button> inside of the <modal> tag, not inside of the component. That way I can close a modal in many different ways, yet have a single modal component.

Comment: Well then it's even easier but you have to follow the same approach... I'll add to my answer

Comment: @peaceman, Maybe you can help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451971/how-can-i-display-modal-in-modal-on-vue-component

Answer (score 0):

#### Vue2 with bootstrap5

or whatever bootstrap version you have,  when bootstrap opens a modal it adds 2 classes `.fade .show` if you don't know what classes it adds in your BS version you can inspect an opened modal and see
then try this:

###### `document.documentElement.querySelector(".modal.fade.show .btn-close").click();`